# how to wait volley respons to load recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have to load recycleview in a fragment.I will tell my problem on an example.
In my recycleview there are 20-30 people's contact.But their phone numbers changes in every 30 minutes.So when contacts button(?) clicked in my bottom navbar i have to get all up-to-date phone numbers in order to load recycleview with correct phone numbers.

My solutions for this was the putting adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method to OnResponseListener. As you can imagine in every volley response recycleview is updating(looks really bad at gui).

Another solution that i found on internet is using AsyncTask. But volley uses its own threads so it looks we are on the dead end again.

Comment: Have you tried waiting until all the volley requests are done, and then calling notifyDataSetChanged once you have all the data so that way it all updates at once?

Comment: i dont know how can i wait until all the requests are done.@TomerShemesh

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, and count how many requests are going and when you don't have anymore, update the list.

```
        int requestsSent = 30;
        requestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        for(int i =0; i < requestsSent; i++)
        {
            mRequestQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "my url", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    requestsSent--;
                    if(requestsSent == 0)
                    {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    requestsSent--;
                }
            }));
        }
```

Comment: in this solution for example requestsSent = 27 can be executed after requestSent= 30 So one or more phone numbers might be not up-to-date.